# How do I remove an Element from an XML in C#

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following XML File:

```
<HOUSE>
  <LOCATION>Random</LOCATION>
  <SERVER>A</SERVER>
  <SERVER>B</SERVER>
  <SERVER>C</SERVER>
  <SERVER>D</SERVER>
  <SERVER>E</SERVER>
  <SERVER>F</SERVER>
</HOUSE>
```

I'm using a `ListBox` that stores the SERVER items and I want add a function that removes a selected item from the listbox and the XML file.
I've tried using:

```
doc.Element("HOUSE")
   .Element("SERVER")
   .Element(Serverslstbox.SelectedItem.ToString())
   .Remove();
```

and

```
XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
        XmlNode remove= root.SelectSingleNode(Serverslstbox.SelectedItem.ToString());
        doc.ParentNode.RemoveChild(remove);
```

and many other options but none of them seem to work, any suggestions?

Comment: What is the value of `Serverslstbox.SelectedItem.ToString()`? A string containing "A", "B" ...?

Comment: What do you mean by "none of them seem to work"? Are you getting some exceptions at runtime? Also make sure you're saving the result after modifying xml content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `Serverslstbox.SelectedItem` contains the name of the server like "A", "B"...

Then you need to use `Where` to filter the elements by their value like this:

```
doc.Element("HOUSE")
    .Elements("SERVER")
    .Where(x => x.Value == Serverslstbox.SelectedItem.ToString())
    .Remove();
```

The above query will remove all "SERVER" elements inside the "HOUSE" element where the value equals the selected item value.

To save the result to a file use the `Save` method like this:

```
doc.Save(filename);
```